# Interchange the display order in a loop

Tags: php

I am trying to interchange the display order in a loop.
 
For example i have an array `$array` with values: `1,2,3,4,5` and want to display the result in the order `2,1,3,4,5`. 
I am using the following code for the purpose and which worked for me:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
);
$tempArray = array();
$count = 1;
foreach($array as $key => $value){
    $tempArray[$key] = $value;
    if(in_array($count, array(1, 2))){
        if($count == 2){
            echo $tempArray[1] . '<br />';
            echo $tempArray[0] . '<br />';
        }
    }else{
        echo $value . '<br />';
    }
    $count++;
}
```

But i would like to know if there is any effective (better) way of doing so?

**EDIT**:

```
$array = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
);
//Either
/*$temp = $array[1];
$array[1] = $array[0];
$array[0] = $temp;*/

//OR
list($array[1], $array[0]) = array($array[0], $array[1]);

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

Either way works fine with minimum code. 
Thank you guys!

Comment: What should be the output for `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` ?

Comment: Is there no other 'ordering' field you could add to the entries, ie `array( array(1, 2), array(2, 1), ...)` which you can then just use `usort` for?

Comment: What criteria do you use to re-order the array?  Do you always swap the 1st and 2nd elements?  If so, why not just swap the elements in the array?  `$temp = $array[1];  $array[1] = $array[0]; $array[0] = $temp;`?

Comment: Output will be 2,1,3,4,5 which means i want to change the occurring of 1st and 2nd elements.

Answer (score 1):

To change the display order of `$array` that is `array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` without changing the order of the elements in `$array` you need to define the display order and then display based on the display order:

```
$array   = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

$display = array_keys($array);
list($display[1], $display[0]) = array($display[0], $display[1]);

foreach ($display as $key)
{
    $value = $array[$key];
    printf("%d<br />\n", $value);
}
```

This works - as you wrote it already yourself in the comments - by switching the order (keys) of the first two elements(`0` and `1`, arrays are zero-based).